# MVC authorize not authenticate using AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, active-directory, authorize

I have scoured this and many other sites to find an answer but have come up short every single time. If this is a duplicate, I am very happy to accept direction to the original question with an answer:

I have built an MVC 4 site and I am using the Authorize tag where needed and this is working as expected.

My issue is that I require a mechanism by which to prompt the user (already logged in or some other valid user in the domain) to enter their windows credentials on one page in order to confirm/authorize that user. This is not what the authorize filter is doing. The authorize filter is actually authenticating the user. Thus changing the User.Identity information accordingly.

Is it possible to just authorize a user (not authenticate) without actually changing the User object?

Just returning the 401 response forces the windows prompt but that, in turn, does an authentication, not an authorize.

While a solution could be achieved with a custom action that accepts username/password input, my requirement specifically calls for the native browser windows prompt to be displayed.

The site is using IIS Express and is set up for windows authentication and every aspect of this does what I need. Except for the issue of "true" authorization mentioned above. The browser has to be IE9. Currently running on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You're currently using Windows Authentication, and this is how it works. There is no need to login because the user is already logged into Windows, that's the point.

To do what you want, you would need to use an individual auth library like Identity. Which will give you the login capability. However, that doesn't work with AD out of the box, but you *can* add that in yourself. In otherwords, instead of using the Identity functionality to look a user up by username and password to authenticate, you'd connect to AD over LDAP, and verify the credentials there. You'd also need to use the LDAP connection to add the user's groups in AD to the their roles in Identity. Then, you can utilize the `Authorize` attribute as normal.

Long and short, if you want to actually allow the user to login as any AD user, then you're pretty much on your own. There's no builtin functionality for that. It's relatively straight-forward, if not entirely easy, to set something up yourself for that that, but again, that's on you.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time out to answer. I will mark this as answer. Its really unfortunate that theres a differentiation between authorize and authenticate but no built in capability to separate the two. Especially considering that the Authorize filter  appears to be a misnomer.